# error opening CSLA solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, csla

I have downloaded cslalightcs and when I try to open cslalightcs.sln I get an error message saying "The project file c:cslalightcs\csla\cslalight.csproject cannot be opened.  The project type is not supported but this installation"

I have opened C# files before.  Anyone know why I am getting this message?

I am using VS 2008.

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Silverlight Tools for VS2008 installed?  (http://silverlight.net/getstarted/) CSLA Light uses a Silverlight library.  With the separate Tools installed (not part of the base VS2008 install), you will get an error about an unknown project type.

Comment: I loaded the Silverlight 3 toolkit.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I grabbed the latest version of CSLALight (3.8.1-091111) from Rocky's site and I don't see a cslalight.csproject file in the solution.  There is a cslalight.csproj file, which is the normal C# project file.  If you file is actually cslalight.csproject, can you rename to cslalight.csproj and try to re-add to the solution to see if that helps?